# Issue with soil multiparameter sensor readings

Tags: modbus, stm32cubeide, rs485

I'm working on the Soil muti parameter sensor which can measure 7 parameters (Temperature, Humidity, Ph, Soil conductivity, N,P,K). I found a manual document of this sensor from a company. I used an inquiry frame that is used to get all the parameter values to one response frame, is mentioned in the manual. It gave the readings for all the parameters but values of N,P,K are constant in different soil samples all the time( even in the open air) [n=32,p=88,k=104]. [image: All parameters have accurate readings except n,p,k]

I implemented this code on STM32CubeIDE. The inquiry frame that I used is in the below image.[image: Inquiry frame mentioned in the manual]

I did try several inquiry frames but they showed inaccurate values or zero values. I am using the RS485 to ttl modbus adapter to get the sensor output to the microcontroller([ttl-to-rs485-power-supply-converter-board](https://lk-tronics.com/product/ttl-to-rs485-power-supply-converter-board/)).

So, my issue is n,p and k values not varying in different soil environments. What is the cause of this issue and what is the solution I can take for this? and additionally, I would like to know is there a way to reset the device .

Comment: If you were able to get all of the values and all of them aside from N, P, and K seem right (at least temperature and humidity in open air), then I'd think that something is wrong with the sensor and doesn't have much to do with Modbus or RS485. Do you have a second sensor you can test with the same setup? If you use ComTest or Modbus Poll, do you get the same readings as you do with the STM board? If you do - again, not a Modbus issue. If you get the right readings with one of those tools, post the sensor info, the manual, and the code that you've used to query the sensor.

Comment: Have you ruled out hardware issues? Have you tried another sensor? Did you respect the voltages all things operate at? Do other readings make sense? How exactly do you send and receive data, maybe something wrong on how you handle data traffic (receiver expects wrong number of bytes or something of that kind)